# How to get the domain of $f(x)=(32x^2+28x^5+4x^8-x^{11})^{-\frac{3}{4}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I'm really sorry if this is not a place to ask this but I really don't know to who to turn with this, so I decided, better to ask than regret not doing so later.
I've put the function into Wolfram so far but sadly it doesn't generate steps for domain solutions.

$f(x)=(32x^2+28x^5+4x^8-x^{11})^{-\frac{3}{4}}$

The domain is x $\in (-\infty;-\sqrt[3]{2})\cup(-\sqrt[3]{2};0)\cup(0;2)$. I have no idea though what is the reasoning behind this.

There definitely is a way to solve this on paper because it's a test question for a university. This one I just really don't know how to approach. So please, smart people of the internet, help me out if you've got a little bit of spare time. I will be very thankful for any help.

Comment: @KemonoChen I rolled back your edit because, although it did remove extraneous information, it also removed context, making the question more likely to be closed.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you for your kind explanation. I won't do that again next time.

Comment: @KemonoChen Please don't let me stop you trying to clean up questions! It's a valuable service, but in this one particular case, you cleaned up a little too much. It's worth being a little more careful on homework-style questions (like this one, even though it isn't homework), as ones with less context tend to be received more harshly.

Comment: @TheoBendit What I meant should be that I won't clean up this type of context. Actually, I don't agree that this type of content can be called "context", but I will still try to understand the standard of the community. It's getting more conversational, further discussion should be in chat room.

Comment: @KemonoChen The meta consensus is that context is anything that aids the users in figuring out what level of maturity/understanding OP has to best serve an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these sorts of questions, usually, there are only a couple of things to look for.

You can't divide by zero, and you can't take a square root of a negative number and get a real result.

Less common, but it shows up in this case, you also can't take a 4th root of a negative either. Or, any case where you see something like $(x)^{\frac {m}{2n}}$ i.e. a fractional exponent with an even denominator.

And since the expression is to a negative power, we would be dividing by zero if everything inside the brackets equals 0.

The question then comes down to, where is

$32x^2 + 28x^5 + 4x^8 - x^{11} > 0$

It bit of a monster to find the roots, but not impossible.  We can start by factoring out  $x^2$

$x^2(32 + 28x^3 + 4x^6 - x^9)$

And if we say $u= x^3$ this gives us a cubic.

$x^2(32 + 28u + 4u^2 - u^3)$

But, it looks like this cubic has rational roots.  If it didn't we could look to the cubic formula.

Potential rational roots are $\{\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 4, \pm 8, \pm 16, \pm 32\}$

Testing each of these we get:

$-x^2(u-8)(u+2)^2$

This is negative when $u>8$ or $x>2$

It is zero when $x = 0,$ and $u = -2$ (i.e. $x=(-2)^\frac 13$) and $x = 2$

Answer (score 0):

In order for $$b^{-3/4}$$ to be well defined you have to have $b>0$

The intervals in the answer are where your base function is positive.